# How to send text between Android and TI BLE CC2541?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am developing an application where I have to connect to Bluetooth device on Android 4.3.

And I want to bilateral communicate between Android APP and  CC2541 Keyfob.

**My ideas is:**

**1.** I connect to the CC2541 keyfob and send the Text data from my APP to CC2541 Keyfob.

**2.** And the CC2541 keyfob will show the text on the PC via UART after it receive the text from Android APP.

**3.** After CC2541 keyfob receive the text , it will send the text back to the Android APP.

**The question like the following:**

**1.** Which profile and service should I use to send the text data??

**2.** How to send the text data to CC2541 keyfob in Android application 4.3 ??

**3.** How to receive the text data on CC2541 side ??

Comment: I am also want to implement same idea. Please check the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26800606/ble-4-0-getting-the-broadcast-data-from-device-to-phone

Answer (score 0):

If your app is the only user of the keyfob you could decide on your own protocol. Also see this post and answers: [How to send the text data to CC2541 keyfob via Android 4.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763777/how-to-send-the-text-data-to-cc2541-keyfob-via-android-4-3)
And this one: [Android: Bluetooth Low Energy GATT Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21506237/android-bluetooth-low-energy-gatt-profile?rq=1)